# Im able to find the quantile but am confused about how to then find the greater values

Tags: python, pandas

Using df, count the number of rows where car width is greater than the 49th percentile for car width.

```py
print("This is the 49th percentile for car Width:")
df['car_width'].quantile([.84])

(df['car_width']>"the percentile value")
```

I am expecting a list but am getting true/false statements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, that is what a boolean expression (such as `==`, `isin(...)`, or in your case `>`) means on series: a series of boolean.

If you want to get the lines matching true values in this series (which is obviously what you want: rows such as `(df['car_width']>"the percentile value")`, get it by using indexing with this boolean series.

`df[SeriesOfbool]` is the sub-df, made of rows for which `seriesOfBool` is True (or at least truthy).

So, here

```py
df[(df['car_width']>"the percentile value")]
```